# Implementing Conditional TypeScript Props Based on the Values of Another Prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface

I have an interface `FilterActionsProps` that defines props for a component. Currently, it supports actions as an array of strings (`['export', 'reset', 'submit']`). However, I need more accurate TypeScript IntelliSense support.

```
interface FilterActionsProps {
   onExport?: () => Promise<void>;
   onReset?: () => void;
   onSubmit?: () => void;
   actions?: ('export' | 'reset' | 'submit')[];
}
```

**Desired Behavior:**

I want to enhance the type support so that when certain actions are specified in the array, only the corresponding props are suggested in TypeScript IntelliSense.

If actions include only `'submit'`, then only `onSubmit` prop should be suggested.

If actions include both `'submit'` and `'reset'`, then both `onSubmit` and `onReset` props should be suggested.

If actions include both `'submit'` and `'export'`, then both `onSubmit` and `onExport` props should be suggested.

If actions include all three `'submit'`, `'reset'`, and `'export'`, then all three `onSubmit`, `onReset`, and `onExport` props should be suggested.

Example Usage:

```
// Only onSubmit prop should be suggested
<Component actions={['submit']} onSubmit={() => {}} />

// Both onSubmit and onReset props should be suggested
<Component actions={['submit', 'reset']} onReset={() => {}} />

// Both onSubmit and onExport props should be suggested
<Component actions={['submit', 'export']} onSubmit={() => {}} onExport={() => Promise.resolve()} />

// All three onSubmit, onReset, and onExport props should be suggested
<Component actions={['submit', 'reset', 'export']} onSubmit={() => {}} onReset={() => {}} onExport={() => Promise.resolve()} />
```

Comment: You have `onExport={() => {}}` in your examples, but you've shown the return type of `onExport` to be `Promise<void>`, not just `void`. Which is right?

Comment: you're right, my bad. However, it doesn't matter; in my code, this function is going to return a promise. For simplicity, I made my example like that.

Comment: It matters to answers. You're saying that yes, the return type of `onExport` should be `Promise<void>`?

Comment: yes  onExport should be Promise<void>

Comment: Do you have a better solution?

Comment: The odds of my having a better solution than caption yossarian from Ukraine are low. :-D (He's v. v. good at TypeScript.) In particular I'm struggling to make the return types right. But unfortunately, your question was unclear and he's used `void` as the return type of all of the handlers and provided a means of excluding `onSubmit` (presumably because the examples didn't include `onSubmit` nor did the type in the first code block in the question). I've updated the question to fix the various things I think are errors; if you'd double-check it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```js
import React from 'react'


type RemapKeys<T extends Record<string, unknown>> = {
    [Prop in keyof T as  `on${Capitalize<Prop & string>}`]: T[Prop]
}

type Props<ActionList extends string[], Excluded extends string> = {
    actions: ActionList
} & RemapKeys<{
    [Prop in Exclude<ActionList[number], Excluded>]: () => void
}>


const App = <
    Action extends string,
    ActionList extends Action[]
>(props: Props<[...ActionList], 'submit'>) => {
    return <div></div>
}


const jsx = <App actions={['reset', 'submit']} onReset={() => { }} /> // ok
const _ = <App actions={['submit']} /> // ok
const __ = <App actions={['reset', 'submit']} onReset={() => { }} onSubmit={() => { }} /> // error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8g7dW)

`RemapKeys` - see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as). It is called key remapping. When you iterate through keys and rename each key according to some pattern.IN this case you wanted `on` prefix to be added.

`Props`  uses tyoe inference in order to infer exact list of string. Please keep in mind - it will work only with literal array or `as const` array. Props expected `ActionList` assigns it to `action` property and creates companion object with help of `REmapKeys`. It just iterates through each element in the array end creates appropriate object with `on${Pattern}` key

If you are interested in TypeScript type inference you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

Comment: The question is a bit unclear about it, but it seems to me from the first code block in the question that the `onExport` handler is supposed to return a promise (even though the OP's example doesn't). That was where I was stuck trying to answer this, I kept ending up with `void | Promise<void>` as the handler return type(s)... I've asked the OP to clarify. I'm sure it's nothing you'll have any trouble with if they did mean `onExport` to return a promise. :-)

Comment: The OP has now confirmed that `onExport`'s return type should be `Promise<void>`.

Comment: I couldn't implement your type with my code. I would greatly appreciate it if you could fit your example into this code.



`{actions.includes('export') && (
        <Button
          type="button"
          _size="sm"
          _text_weight="bold"
          _margin_right="md"
          _color="gray"
          onClick={onExport}
        >
          Export
        </Button>
      )}`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder did not even think about Promises, thank you

Comment: @AliEhyaie please update your question as well

Comment: @AliEhyaie your example here dont match with example in the question. Here you dont use actions as a prop

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something simple, then you can refactor your prop structure slightly to match this

```js
interface Submit {
    action: "submit",
    onSubmit: () => void
}

interface Reset {
    action: "reset",
    onReset: () => void
}

interface Export {
    action: "export",
    onExport: () => void
}

type Actions = (Submit | Reset | Export) [];

let prop: Actions = [{
    action: "export",
    onExport: () => {}
}, {
    action: "reset",
    onReset: () => {}
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

1. The return type of `onSubmit` and `onReset` should be `void`.
2. The return type of `onExport` should be `Promise<void>`.
3. All three handlers are optional even if their associated actions are specified.
4. But you shouldn't be able to provide a handler for an action that isn't specified (nor should it be suggested for code completion).

Based on that, here is my solution:

```typescript
// The available actions
type FilterActions = "export" | "reset" | "submit";

// The available handlers and their return types
type FilterActionHandlers = {
    onExport?: () => Promise<void>;
    onSubmit?: () => void;
    onReset?: () => void;
};

// Converts an action name to a handler name
type HandlerName<Action extends FilterActions> = `on${Capitalize<Action>}`;

// The props for our component
type FilterActionsProps<Actions extends FilterActions[]> = Pick<
    FilterActionHandlers,
    HandlerName<Actions[number]>
> & { actions: Actions };

// Our component
function Example<Actions extends FilterActions[]>(props: FilterActionsProps<Actions>) {
    // ...
}
```

Examples:

```typescript
// Only onSubmit prop should be suggested
const a = <Example actions={["submit"]} onSubmit={() => {}} />;

// Both onSubmit and onReset props should be suggested
const b = <Example actions={["submit", "reset"]} onReset={() => {}} />;

// Both onSubmit and onExport props should be suggested
const c = <Example actions={["submit", "export"]} onSubmit={() => {}} onExport={() => Promise.resolve()} />;

// All three onSubmit, onReset, and onExport props should be suggested
const d = <Example actions={["submit", "reset", "export"]} onSubmit={() => {}} onReset={() => {}} onExport={() => Promise.resolve()} />;

// Error, because there's no `"export"` in the actions list
const e = <Example actions={["submit", "reset"]} onExport={() => Promise.resolve()} />;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsFNQQwG5wJYBs4CNWzgYwC7ID2AdgM4BQ+AngA6wBia+0ATgIIHHmgC8oAImgAPWkVb4BoAD6DW0MtEkzBZAK4YAtskkBuChRAQY8JGkzZQkOCQAm2VmXh3Q+GMlah5+NaxKu6BSpA0CZUFg4uUgAJG3s2J34AbwpQNNBSAFFRcXwAfgAuUAAKAEo+AD5QAAVWIm1FAB4EImRbCv10jJIAZQ1tfKKyytAWts700gAlBSVCkvLeKrHbfQBffUMwAGFSBDZ8Jxt4KP8SOE1YfCJ4KziHUHPL4PpQWLsHADkL6EbOQlIoBELDsTjCEX+3DIVX4AANSAASJLbOC0HRwVDIABev0hpAqa1hmyMUFgtDqtCcADNxBlfKBcPUxCRoCR8C9GMw2HjyLUiJS-qcnMDWbYwVzIgDyABtAC6MJqyFwAGtGql0uDuad3vFHAAadVpHVfH6CqVkaUkNSaDBseUUKoAMlASRO5qKPKcGwMRgA8vTGZpmaz2VS1CRTqBshdaNgzVCgcIQWLQhLPXKKsVyfyyEVNZKoXyBZ6KuUUl0jAApNRkfC3EikRTkWDeXz+JCoNSwMg3HQAcicilZrhurb8ziB2EubIKhq8SjboEatmQCBdADpN1mKUcjiRqKU1qBgB0KGsfWBo0HsLmL6BfSRUNRun0tDpQNnaKAyJAiGpULYoC2t+agAOagQoLC2BQjLkHWcB8EuV6xjgQq8Ek0oCOob6SLKR6kK+AzocMSwumsR4nsSYAAEJEG4L79O+cTdDMih1p+g6-v+gHAeo4GQdA0GwbWQGIY0yGWHg5roZh2EDAIepyLMuH4SQrFKMRixVEk5HHqeWygLR9EEYx8EuFkOQSB+O7flxAFAd2YEQbWgkwY2da4GJEmodJGFYaZCmCCIYgSAIeEMThmkjDpqnZCF+BRaRfINNA67yD2qD7GUFH6UY7CoKgriQPIsAmThinTMpinMRZ8XWTmtl-vZvFOQJQnuaAgH8OJwgxpJaF+XJOiBQI6VKCNwW5GFqmEToiXabplVsfNZGxZZCVJCRVTJcgihpQoRCZdA2V6VRUasHUrCKbauBwDWVwwPIA6PDcsJCOtAiwqAyD+G4PkJpitZuXBQJeb117-Y2Mn+ThI1jSp3RxbkK07Xt6WHVlh6nUAA)

I've used a type that lists the possible handlers so we can readily pick the properties from it that we need, mapping action names to handler names using a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#handbook-content) and the [`Capitalize`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#capitalizestringtype) utility function.